# Find a basis for and the dimensions of the following subspaces...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find a basis for and the dimensions of the following subspaces...

The space of solutions to the linear system $Ax = 0$ where $A$ is the following matrix

$$
A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\ 3 & 0 & 2 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
I'm not sure how to start this, but my intuition is telling me that i need to set a system of linear equations and find the solutions for $x$. but once i find the solutions, what am i supposed to do with them?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking for the kernel of the following matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1&1\\3&0&2&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which reading off the leading ones, we can see quickly should have dimension $2$ by rank nullity.

Finding a basis is the same as solving the augmented matrix represented system 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1&1&\vdots&0\\3&0&2&-1&\vdots&0\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2/3&-1/3&\vdots&0\\0&1&-5/6&4/6&\vdots&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
which suggests the following vectors span the subspace
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/3w-2/3z\\5/6z-2/3w\\z\\w\end{bmatrix}=w\begin{bmatrix}1/3\\-2/3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}-2/3\\5/6\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Being polite and giving integer valued vectors, your basis is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\0\\3\end{bmatrix},\;\begin{bmatrix}-4\\5\\6\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Can you explain to me how exactly you got the two integer valued vectors at the end of your post?

Comment: scaling vectors a matrix sends to zero gives you another perhaps prettier vector that still gets sent to zero

Comment: im not sure what you mean, can you explain it in a different way?

Comment: If you have a vector $v$ which satisfies $Av=0$ for some matrix $A$, then for a scalar $\lambda$, $A(\lambda v)=\lambda Av=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The set of solutions of this linear system (namely $V$) is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ (assuming the problem is considered over the real numbers) and we are looking for the dimension and a basis of this subspace.

The dimension of $V$ is rather easy to find. Start computing the rank of this matrix (which you'll see that it is 2). Now, the dimension of $V$ is just the number of variables minus the rank, so in this case, we have $\dim(V) = 4 - 2 = 2$. Intuitively, this is so because the rank of a matrix essentially tells you how many rows in the matrix give you information about the solutions of the system. The higher the rank, the more information you have about your solutions. Having more information means having more restrictions, which translates to "less" solutions.

Now, we know that we have to find two linearly independent vectors $v_1, v_2$ such that $V = \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle$; that is, any solution $v = (x,y,z,t)$ of the system might be written uniquely as 
$$
v = \alpha v_1 + \beta v_2
$$
To do so, just solve the system. You will find two equations giving you the values of, say, $x$ and $y$, depending on $z$ and $t$. Now, just take $z=1$ and $t=0$, and then $z=0$ and $t=1$. This automatically guaranties that the solutions you find this way are linearly independent.